# Are there any formal definitions or statistical theories about this kind of events?

Tags: time-series, descriptive-statistics

Say a basketball team wins a game. Obviously, at some point in the future, the basketball team will lose a game. So hence, after each game that the basketball team wins, the team is edging closer to their next lost. Are there any statistical tools that can help predict or explain this kind of situations?

Another example would be the stock market, which can either close higher or close lower after each day. If a stock market closes higher today, eventually one day it will close lower. That day would be approaching nearer. Are there any statistical tools or tests that can help model or predict these kind of events? For example, the stock market closes up for the past 4 days in a row, so what is the probability that it will close up tomorrow?

To get a better idea of what Im trying to explain. Lets say for example the past 5 game results (game 5 being the most recent) of a basketball team are:

> Game 1: Win
>
> Game 2: Win
>
> Game 3: Win
>
> Game 4: Win
>
> Game 5: Lose

So from Game 1 to Game 4, after each win, the team's next lost is approaching closer. Are there any statistical tools for these kind of situations?

Comment: You may be interested in reading about the [negative binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

Comment: Thanks, seems like what I wanted! Will explore more on that.

Comment: This sounds perilously close to Gambler's Fallacy territory  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy but it's possible this is a negative binomial question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you had reason to assume that the past outcomes directly influence the future, then the probability of each event remains constant at each step in the sequence.

Imagine flipping a coin with probability of heads = 0.5, and you flip it 5 times. Even if it comes up tails on 4 consecutive flips, the $P(heads)$ on the 5th flip is the same, 0.5.

Comment: Thanks, I know on the 5th flip, the probability is 0.5. What Im saying is, if you flip the coin infinitely many times, there will obviously be both heads and tails. Say the first 5 flips are HHHHT. So when you look back at the results of the first 5 flips (HHHHT), you can say after the 1st flip: "after 3 more flips of Heads, a Tail will appear)". Meaning, after each flip of Head, we are getting closer to the appearance of a tail. Are there any statistical theories about this kind of events?

Comment: After each flip yielding a Head, we are getting closer to another flip.  It is only in *selected situations*, with the benefit of *hindsight*, that one could say it turned out we were getting closer to a Tail.  Generally speaking, though, with each Head we have reason for neither more nor less of an expectation of seeing a Tail on the next flip.  So, like @jerad, I disagree with what I perceive to be the premise behind your question.

Comment: @Richard80, Sorry, but I guess I dont understand the kind of problem you're referring to. The case you describe is difficult to interpret because if you knew that *"after 3 more flips of Heads, a Tail will appear"* you would have no need for statistics. But perhaps I'm confused..please correct me if so.

Comment: @Richard80  'you can say after the 1st flip: "after 3 more flips of Heads, a Tail will appear)" ' -- such things are only possible post-hoc. Before you toss, the probability is unaltered by the history of the coin toss. *The coin has no memory*

Comment: Thanks, I just saw a comment above, Negative Binomial distribution. I think thats what I was looking for.